# Bonus pool cut via collective punishment for not completing training

Tags: united-states, training, bonus

All employees of the company I work at have been instructed to complete certain internal training. It is easy to complete, and shouldn't cause a problem for any individual. We have been given about a month to do this. (Of course, I expect there are employees who will be on holiday/leave for this entire window.)

We have been told that the size of the bonus pool will be affected if less than 100% of employees complete this training. We haven't been given details of how much less of a bonus we will receive. To my mind this is effectively collective punishment i.e. employees receive less of a bonus if *someone else* doesn't complete the training.

My understanding is that bonuses are exactly that: bonus, and not guaranteed. But is the company within their rights to cut everyone's bonuses in this manner?

Comment: Why would you think that bonuses are not under company control?

Comment: Unless the bonus forms part of your contract, the business is likely to have a wide range of discretionary power regarding the conditions around the payment of bonuses. However, I am almost certain that the company does not have any figures in mind at this stage. It's most likely just some statement they made to encourage people to attend training.

Comment: Whether they were within their rights or not (and I believe they probably are), I would NOT continue to work for such a company.

Comment: @JonCuster I understand that bonuses are under company control.

Comment: It seems to me that someone has had a 'bright idea' as to how to save money this year...

Comment: If your company wants to enforce or encourage training, they should only reduce bonus for employees who do not complete the training yet, and after they complete the training, they can get 100% of the bonus. However,  employees who complete the training should always get 100% the bonus.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I work at a company where we also get bonuses, and they are based on various things, including how profitable and how safe we are.  How profitable is because of both market actions, and the actions of me and my co-workers together.  How safe is definitely the actions of me and my co-workers together.  If together, we do well, then the bonus is larger.

Essentially, your company is just giving you the glass half empty instead of the glass half full view of the bonus: if together you don't do well, then the bonus will be smaller.

If we are unsafe and cause accidents, our bonus will be smaller.  Even if I personally am safe, those accidents cost the company money, and there will be less bonus money available.  I don't know if lack of training might cost your company, but in any case, it is quite normal for bonuses to be based on the actions of the entire group.

Comment: Thank you for framing this differently to how I had been thinking about it +1